# How to rsync root files over non-root ssh?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sudo

I have two machines, both providing no root login, but provide `sudo` root access.

Now I like to initate a `rsync` transfer of root files over ssh. Is there an easy way make the the root access given by `sudo` visible to an non-interactive ssh session to allow `rsync` transfer as root? Something better than for example having `rsync` use `ssh` with `sudo` and `sshpass` to allow rsync do the sudo login?

Comment: Is important that the files have root ownership on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, the target should equal the source machine. If synching config files in `/etc` for example, they should keep root ownership.

Comment: If you do not find any other solution a _mad suggestion_ can be to mount as remote filesystem the remote `/etc` as local `/Remote_etc` and after to do a slow  `sudo rsync` between `/etc` and  `/Remote_etc`. I need to deserve my nickname sometime :)

Comment: Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92123/rsync-all-files-of-remote-machine-over-ssh-without-root-user